# How to set an image mouseover for wordpress widget bar

Tags: wordpress, onmouseover

I would like an image to change on mouseover in Wordpress sidebar using widgets. I've added the image but not sure how to set it so it changes when hovered over it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<img src="image.gif"
onmouseover="this.src='image 2.gif'"
onmouseout="this.src='image.gif'">
```